# Building a store locator app using distance between two coordinates

Tags: php, web-services, web, gps, distance

I am making a small section of an app (phone and website) that can find the nearest stores (stored in my database). I am using PHP so was going to make use of the web service idea and have AJAX requests posted to a PHP Page. I have found the following info from snipplr.com:

```
    function distance($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2, $miles = true)
{
    $pi80 = M_PI / 180;
    $lat1 *= $pi80;
    $lng1 *= $pi80;
    $lat2 *= $pi80;
    $lng2 *= $pi80;

    $r = 6372.797; // mean radius of Earth in km
    $dlat = $lat2 - $lat1;
    $dlng = $lng2 - $lng1;
    $a = sin($dlat / 2) * sin($dlat / 2) + cos($lat1) * cos($lat2) * sin($dlng / 2) * sin($dlng / 2);
    $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));
    $km = $r * $c;

    return ($miles ? ($km * 0.621371192) : $km);
}
```

Which is all good, but I have a database of about 300 locations. I just need bit of help getting started with this.

My idea was to do a query to a DB and get all of the long/lats in an array and loop through the array, each time using this above function. Then sort the requests by distance and done!

But I just wondered if theres a better way? I am relatively new to PHP development, so need to get an idea about best practices etc...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are you not using the geospatial indexes provided in many DBs like SQL and MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd actually advice you to check out the solution of google. this works pretty well:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch?hl=en

Comment: before I forget: http://www.facebook.com/bluntch/app_118220448265736 here's a working sample. > type i.e. Sidney into the searchfield...

Comment: Does this have any usage limits? Because I was going to use the JS v3 API but it says you can only search 25 orgins and/or 25 destinations?

Comment: Well we've not had any troubles with that yet.. i mean it's on facebook, many clicks on it and we feed about 200-up to 1000 shop-locations from our database... so i think it's not limited so far... actually: I don't think so - but I am not 100% sure to be honest

Comment: by the way... I'd advice you to drop this question directly on the google-board which is available on the mentioned site... i am pretty sure they gonna answer this - just 'cos it's not described very precisely on their site...